# How to make a autocompleting dropdown menu in textfield in GUI swing java by using file handling just like any search engine?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

As i am making a dictionary application and i want to add a dropdown menu of words in search textfield(where user enters words to search from dictionary).Now i want to show words list user has already searched just like any search engine.I am using treemap and file handling for storage and sorting of words and i tried to pass the array of searched words in comboBox but now i can't handle this thing everytime i get some error or no result.

Kindly suggest me something or change my code according to my requirements.

Following are my dictionary(Treemap,filehandling),Searchword(creates frame for search button) and menuFrame(handles overall frame of application) classes.

`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Dictionary {
    private static boolean modified = false;
    private static String dictionaryfile;

    static  {
         dictionaryfile =  System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/dictionary.ser";
    }

    public static boolean isModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    private static String message = "";

    public static String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public static void setMessage(String message) {
        Dictionary.message = message;
    }
    private static TreeMap<String, String> words = new TreeMap<String,String>();

    public static TreeMap<String,String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public static void setWords(TreeMap<String,String> words) {
        Dictionary.words = words;
        modified = true;
    }

    public static String searchWord(String word) {

        return words.get(word);
    }
    public static void addWord(String word, String meaning) {
        words.put(word,meaning);
        modified = true;
    }

    public static boolean deleteWord(String word) {
        Object done =  words.remove(word);
        if ( done == null)
            return false;
        else {
            modified = true;
            return true;
        }
    }


    public static boolean saveToDisk() {
        // create file and save to disk
        try  {
        System.out.println(dictionaryfile);
        FileOutputStream fs= new FileOutputStream(dictionaryfile);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(words);
        os.close();
        fs.close();
        modified = false;
        return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            message = ex.getMessage();
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static String loadFromDisk() {
        // read words from serialized treemap
        try  {
        FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(dictionaryfile);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fs);
        words  = (TreeMap) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fs.close();
        modified = false;

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            message = ex.getMessage();

        }

        return words.toString();

    }

}



import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SearchWord extends JFrame{


    private JTextField tfWord;
    private JTextArea  taMeaning;
    private JButton btnSearch;
    Container c;
    JComboBox<String> box=new JComboBox<String>();


    public SearchWord() {
        super("Search Word");

        GridBagLayout gbl  = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(60,5,5,5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        tfWord = new JTextField(20);
        taMeaning = new JTextArea();
        btnSearch = new JButton("Search");



        btnSearch.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 if (  tfWord.getText().length() > 0 ) {
                 String meaning = Dictionary.searchWord(tfWord.getText());
                 searchedUpdate(tfWord.getText());
                 if ( meaning != null)
                       taMeaning.setText(meaning);
                 else
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( SearchWord.this, "Word  Not Found. Please try again!","Search Word", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                 }
                 else
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( SearchWord.this, "Please enter word from dictionary!","Search Word", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

         }
        );


         c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(gbl);

        // add tfWord
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.add( new JLabel("Search Word :"),gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        c.add(tfWord);
        c.add(box);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.add( btnSearch);


        // add taMeaning
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.add( new JLabel("Meaning :"), gbc);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        taMeaning.setRows(3);
        taMeaning.setColumns(30);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(taMeaning, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        c.add(sp, gbc);
        // c.add(cb);
        pack(); // get requried size based on components
    }

    private void searchedUpdate(String s[])
    { 

      for(String x: s) box.addItem(x);
    }

}



import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MenuFrame extends JFrame {

    public MenuFrame() throws Exception {
        super("Dictionary");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        // create menu
        JMenu mnuDictionary = new JMenu("Dictionary");
        mb.add(mnuDictionary);

        // options in Dictionary Menu
        JMenuItem option = new JMenuItem("Add Word...");
        option.setIcon( getImage("add.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F5"));
        mnuDictionary.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                addWord();
            }
        });
        // options in Dictionary Menu
        option = new JMenuItem("Delete Word...");
        option.setIcon( getImage("delete.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F6"));
        mnuDictionary.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                deleteWord();
            }
        });

        //mnuDictionary.addSeparator();

        // options in Dictionary Menu
        option = new JMenuItem("Search Word...");
        option.setIcon( getImage("search.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F7"));
        mnuDictionary.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                searchWord();
            }
        });


        option = new JMenuItem("List Words");
        option.setIcon( getImage("list.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F8"));
        mnuDictionary.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                listWords();
            }
        });

       // mnuDictionary.addSeparator();

        option = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        mnuDictionary.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                exit();
            }
        });

        addStorageMenu(mb);
        addToolbar();
        setJMenuBar(mb);
        mb.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        mb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 5, 5, 5));

        Dictionary.loadFromDisk();

    }

    public void exit() {
        if (Dictionary.isModified()) {
            int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(MenuFrame.this, "You have some pending changes. Do you want to write them to disk and then exit?",
                    "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {  // exit after save
                Dictionary.saveToDisk();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) // exit without saving
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }
        // if cancel then do not exit
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public ImageIcon getImage(String filename){
        return new ImageIcon(  this.getClass().getResource("/images/" + filename));
    }

    public void centerToParent(JFrame parent, JFrame child) {
        Dimension pd = parent.getSize();
        Dimension cd = child.getSize();
       int x = (int) (pd.getWidth() - cd.getWidth()) / 2;
       int y = (int) (pd.getHeight() - cd.getHeight()) / 2;
        child.setLocation(x, y);

    }

    public void addWord() {
        AddWord w = new AddWord();
        centerToParent(MenuFrame.this, w);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void deleteWord() {
        DeleteWord w = new DeleteWord();
        centerToParent(MenuFrame.this, w);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void searchWord() {
        SearchWord w = new SearchWord();
        centerToParent(MenuFrame.this, w);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void listWords() {
        ListWords w = new ListWords();
        w.setVisible(true);
        centerToParent(MenuFrame.this, w);
    }

    public void addToolbar() {
        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar(JToolBar.VERTICAL);
        tb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);




        tb.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(520, 300));
        JButton b = new JButton( getImage("Add.png"));
        b.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(32,32));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("Add Word");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 addWord();
            }

        });tb.addSeparator();


         b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(7,10,10,5)));


        b = new JButton( getImage("delete.gif"));
        b.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(70,00));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("Delete Word");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 deleteWord();
            }

        });
        tb.addSeparator();
         b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10,10,10,1)));

        b = new JButton( getImage("search.gif"));
        b.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(32,32));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("Search Word");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 searchWord();
            }

        });
        tb.addSeparator();
 b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10,10,10,1)));


        b = new JButton( getImage("list.png"));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("List Words");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 listWords();
            }

        });
 b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10,10,10,1)));

        tb.addSeparator();

        b = new JButton( getImage("savee.png"));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("Save Dictionary To Disk");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 Dictionary.saveToDisk();
            }

        });
        tb.addSeparator();
         b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10,10,10,1)));


        b = new JButton( getImage("Load.png"));
        tb.add(b);
        b.setToolTipText("Load Dictionary From Disk");
        b.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 Dictionary.loadFromDisk();
            }

        });
        tb.addSeparator();
         b.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(10,10,10,1)));


        tb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 2, 1, 5));
//tb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());


        tb.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 2,
            javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Separator.background")),
            javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 3,
            javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Separator.foreground"))));
        getContentPane().add(tb, BorderLayout.WEST);
         //getContentPane().add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void addStorageMenu(JMenuBar mb) {

        JMenu mnuStorage = new JMenu("Storage");

        // options in Storage Menu
        JMenuItem option = new JMenuItem("Save Dictionary");
        option.setIcon( getImage("save.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"));
        mnuStorage.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean result = Dictionary.saveToDisk();
                if (result) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuFrame.this, "Saved Dictionary Successfully!", "Feedback",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuFrame.this, "Could Not Save Dictionary Successfully! Error --> " + Dictionary.getMessage(), "Feedback",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });



        option = new JMenuItem("Load Dictionary");
        option.setIcon( getImage("load.gif"));
        option.setAccelerator( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F3"));
        mnuStorage.add(option);
        option.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String result = Dictionary.loadFromDisk();
                if (result == Dictionary.loadFromDisk()) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuFrame.this, "Loaded Dictionary Successfully!", "Feedback",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MenuFrame.this, "Could Not Load Dictionary Successfully! Error --> " + Dictionary.getMessage(), "Feedback",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        mb.add(mnuStorage);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MenuFrame f = new MenuFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please include some more information, for example the error you are getting. You've also pasted a lot of code, it would be easier to help you debug if you just paste the code that is causing the error.

Comment: Actually this code is not showing the required output

Comment: There is some logical error i want to add array of words which user has searched in searchedUpdate method.

Comment: private void searchedUpdate(String s[])
    { 
 
      for(String x: s) box.addItem(x);
    }